# Using Vue.render() vs calling render() from inside app with vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a product page and I got sick of putting tons of Vue code in a div with a class of hidden because a lot of the content is for modals. I found a way to render some Vue code on the fly inside of a javascript function only if the function is invoked.

The cool thing about this is I can refer to the parent app's data, when using normal Vue templates, this is not possible.

This code is not using a build step and Vue is being imported from unpkg.

In the first example I am using `Vue.render()` and this does work, the only thing is I found this answer from chat gpt, and I have never seen this in the docs and I could not find anything on it, but looking at unpkg, a render method is exported and available through `Vue.render()`.

I don't know why there are no docs on this but the second example uses the render method again but inside a Vue app and there is some documentation on this.

I am wondering if anyone can explain the `Vue.render()` method a bit and if one approach is better than the other, and by better I mean more reliable and robust. The render method is documented and shown to be used inside an app.

#### Call `Vue.render()` and render vnode to regular DOM element without creating a new Vue app

```js
const product_app_options = {
  data() {
    return {
      sizeOptions: [/* ... */],
      product: { /* ... */ }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      const vnode = Vue.h(
            'div', 
            { 
              class: [
                'size-modal-swatches',
                'swatches'
              ]
            },
            this.sizeVariants.map(variant => 
              Vue.h(
                'button',
                {
                  class: [
                    { 
                      'soldout': !variant.available,
                      'selected': variant[product.size_option.option] === _this.selected_size
                    },
                    'pw-button',
                    'size-modal__swatch',
                    'swatch'
                  ],
                  tabIndex: 0,
                  onClick: e => _this.selectVariant(e, variant),
                  ariaLabel: variant.available 
                    ? `size ${variant[this.product.size_option.option]} available`
                    : `size ${variant[this.product.size_option.option]} not available`
                },
                [
                  Vue.h(
                    'div',
                    {
                      class: [
                        'pw-button__inner'
                      ]
                    },
                    [
                      Vue.h(
                        'span',
                        {
                          class: [
                            'size-modal__swatch-value'
                          ]
                        },
                        variant[this.product.size_option.option]
                      )
                    ]
                  )
                ]
              )
            )
          );

      // append modal to DOM
      // after appending modal grab it's content selector

      Vue.render(vnode, document.querySelector('.modal-content'))
    }
  }
}
```

#### Call `render()` from inside a Vue app and mount the app to a DOM element

```js
const product_app_options = {
  data() {
    return {
      sizeOptions: [/* ... */],
      product: { /* ... */ }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        render: () => Vue.h(
            'div', 
            { 
              class: [
                'size-modal-swatches',
                'swatches'
              ]
            },
            this.sizeVariants.map(variant => 
              Vue.h(
                'button',
                {
                  class: [
                    { 
                      'soldout': !variant.available,
                      'selected': variant[product.size_option.option] === _this.selected_size
                    },
                    'pw-button',
                    'size-modal__swatch',
                    'swatch'
                  ],
                  tabIndex: 0,
                  onClick: e => _this.selectVariant(e, variant),
                  ariaLabel: variant.available 
                    ? `size ${variant[this.product.size_option.option]} available`
                    : `size ${variant[this.product.size_option.option]} not available`
                },
                [
                  Vue.h(
                    'div',
                    {
                      class: [
                        'pw-button__inner'
                      ]
                    },
                    [
                      Vue.h(
                        'span',
                        {
                          class: [
                            'size-modal__swatch-value'
                          ]
                        },
                        variant[this.product.size_option.option]
                      )
                    ]
                  )
                ]
              )
            )
          );
      })

      // append modal to DOM

      app.mount('.modal-content')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are creating your modal does not make any sense to me.  Especially, by creating a new Vue instance inside of `product_app_options`, which is I expect to be also a Vue app.

The way you use `Vue.render()` to create a VNode and then replace with it an element looks weird.

Why not create a small and nice Vue component with your modal?

Check the Vue Example [Modal with Transitions](https://vuejs.org/examples/#modal) on how to achieve it.

If you really want to render the modal dynamically using [Vue Render Function APIs](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#render-function-apis) then do it in the component `setup()` function.

Like this

```
const MyModal = {
   setup() {
     return () => h('div', null,[
         h( ...
     ])
   }
}
```

Check [Render Functions & JSX](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html) about the details.

```js
const { createApp, ref, h, watch } = Vue;

const MyModal = {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  setup(props, context) {
    return () => !props.modelValue ? null :
         h('div', { class: 'modal-mask'}, 
            h('div', {class: 'modal-container'}, [
                h('div', {class: 'modal-header'}, 'My Modal'),
                h('button', { onClick: () => context.emit('update:modelValue', false) }, 'Close'),
                h('div', context.slots.default()),
              ]
            )  
        )
   }
}

const App = { 
  components: { MyModal },
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.modal-header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #42b983;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<my-modal v-model="showModal">Default Slot</my-modal>
<button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the reason for this is I am using shopify and the options api is in use, otherwise I typically use the composition api. The problem was is that since it's a server side rendered platform, and the way the site is built, the whole site isn't using vue. I can make this work in a few different ways but it annoyed me having to have code in a div with a hidden class, so I wanted it generated on the fly if the user would open a modal. It's a tricky setup that I am dealing with because only certain parts are using vue and there isn't a global component.

Comment: You can do the same using Options API.

Comment: Which is what I did already, I was a bit confused how `Vue.render()` works.